# Identify vegetable with stalks coming out of it

Tags: species-identification, vegetable

I know nothing more about this vegetable than the fact that it is safely edible, which a local vegetable vendor in South India told me. It's green (white inside) and has a strong smell resembling that of cabbage. It has these stalks coming out of folds in the outer skin, as well as a few leaves. STP identify.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is a _kohlrabi_. The leaves are cut off. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlrabi#/media/File:KohlrabiinMarket.jpg

Comment: @ermanen You could probably post an answer.